# How can I restrict rows in a linq query based on a field having at least one entry that matches a row in a string array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code that I have been working on:

```
var menuItems = _contentRepository.GetPk("01" + pk + "000")
    .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
    .Select(m => new Menu.Item
    {
        PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
        RowKey = m.RowKey,
        Order = m.Order,
        Title = m.Title,
        Type = m.Type,
        Link = m.Link,
        TextLength = m.TextLength
    });
```

One of the fields that is returned .GetPk is a field called Roles. This is a string field with contents that show the roles that can access each item of the menu. The data in the field looks like the following:

```
All 
All,Admin 
All,Admin, Super
Admin
Admin, Super
```

I have a string[] roles that is populated with the roles that a user has. If a user has one role then there's one item in the string array, if a user has two roles there are two items. If the user has no role then the array is empty.

How can I make it so my select only returns a value if an entry in the string[] roles matches one of the words in my Roles field?

So far I have been doing some research and I found the following which does almost what I need. But how can I fit this into my Linq above?

```
String[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
var links = from item in menus
    where item.Roles.Split(new String[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Any(x => roles.Contains(x) || x == "All")
    select item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include that condition in a Where clause before you Select the results into the form you need them.

```
var menuItems = _contentRepository.GetPk("01" + pk + "000")
.OrderBy(m => m.Order)
.Where(m => m.Roles.Split(",").Any(x => roles.Contains(x) || x == "All"))
.Select(m => new Menu.Item
{
    PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
    RowKey = m.RowKey,
    Order = m.Order,
    Title = m.Title,
    Type = m.Type,
    Link = m.Link,
    TextLength = m.TextLength
});
```

Comment: It's giving me a message saying the best overloaded match for Split has some invalid parameters?

Comment: replace the "," with single quotes like this ','